# kubernetes tools in portable vscode have issue as it puts the tools in user directory

Tags: kubernetes, visual-studio-code

I have installed kubernetes extension on my vscode portable version.
even if have create the data directory inside the vscode folder.
the tools are getting installed in the C:\Users\ directory as .vs-kubernetes folder

is there any way to have this truely portable ?

The reason i am facing the issue is i am running this on citrix and we have very less user space.

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/vscode-kubernetes-tools/issues/707

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/vscode-kubernetes-tools#portable-extension-configuration